# How do I change the verbosity of the service command?

Tags: systemd, kali-linux

I am running Kali 2 Linux.  I use the `systemctl` or `service` command to start a service such as Apache. On the previous version of Kali the command actually prints an "OK" message when starting a service; but on this version it just drops back to the command-line saying nothing.

Is there a way to change the verbosity or make it behave like the previous version did?

Comment: Well usually when there is no message that means success.

Answer (score 2):

The `service` command (usually on `/usr/sbin/`) is nowadays typically just a `bash` shell script which invokes the `systemctl` command.  You should be easily able to modify it to give the output you wish for.

Answer (score 0):

`journald` Is centralized daemon which collects data from all available sources and stores them in a binary format for easy and dynamic manipulation. As a answer of your question i would say that usually when there is no output that means It's "OK", and if you want to be sure use `journalctl` to check the logs.

Comment: I know, but I like the feeling of the ok message am used to it, and I need it to pop

Comment: Whether the service starts or not, there is no output. I'm tempted to add an alias: service $1 start;service $1 status

Answer (score -1):

You can add an `echo $?` to the command to display a status of 1 or 0.

The `&&` has the effect of only running the second command if the previous is successful.

```
systemctl start mysqld.service && echo $?
```

This will show a status:

if it fails it will print a message why it failed

if it succeeds you will only see 0

You can in your mind append the k 0 = 0k

This is a cheap workaround but will give you an ok return after your systemctl calls.

Comment: ``&& echo $?`` seems like a peculiar thing to do; it will print `0` or nothing at all.  You might as well say `&& echo OK` or `&& echo Success`.

Comment: nope it is not like echo ok. It echos the actual result of the last command. If it is a 0 it was successful. If not successful it will be a 1.

Comment: But you’re saying **`&& echo $?`**! If the (first) command fails, the shell won’t run the second command (the one after the `&&`), and so it won’t print anything!

Comment: No when it fails it will print the message that systemctl sends when the service doesnt start. 
Just try it yourself it does work I have used it. 
For instance (I have to use service calls as RHEL does output on fail or success) 
When a service fails you get standard systemctl fail output
When service starts you get a 0 Would be a 1 the second statement ran (can test with ; instead of && )
Service runs :

Comment: When service runs :
# service httpd start && echo $? 
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start httpd.service
0

When fails : (shows 1 because of ; instead of &&) 
service mysqld restart ; echo $? 
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart mysqld.service
1


PLEASE test this yourself it is easy to try and does work.

Comment: I didn’t say that it didn’t work.  I said that `&& echo $?` works *exactly the same* as `&& echo 0` — the “`$?`” makes it look like you’re doing something more sophisticated than you are — and, as long as you’re going to do something as unsophisticated as `&& echo 0`, you might as well do `&& echo OK`, which will give the result that the question asks for. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Is `echo 0` exactly the same as `echo OK`?  No, of course not; `0` is one character, which is a digit, whereas `OK` is two characters, which are (alphabetic) letters.  Duh. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … Please read the comments again.  You said “It echos the actual result of the last command. … If not successful it will be a 1.”  It was in the context of that comment that I said “it won’t print anything”.  And then please try it yourself.  If you can get ``&& echo $?`` to echo a ``1``, please describe exactly how (including what shell you’re using, complete with version number) so other people can try to reproduce the bug and submit a bug report.

Comment: P.S. Whoever up voted Mark’s comments (and not mine)  —  you might want to avoid taking sides in conversations you don’t understand.

Comment: G-man do your own research on return codes. Not sure if you are trolling or not. There is plenty of info on return results using $?   https://askubuntu.com/questions/324423/how-to-access-the-last-return-value-in-bash

Comment: I don’t understand how you could possibly believe that ***I’m*** trolling ***you**.*  But I shouldn’t be surprised — it seems to me that you haven’t understood anything I’ve said.  I feel no need to do any research — I’m confident that I know what I’m talking about, and that I understand the subject just fine.  But, to be a good sport, I looked at the thread you linked to.  You know that question *isn’t even about return codes,* right? (Yes, some people misunderstood the question and posted answers and comments that talk about return codes, but there’s nothing there that I don’t already know.)